# How to ship a virtual environment/distribution in lieu of binary

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I have a python library, which is mainly centered around a single graphical application.  I had intended to make binaries so that people didn't need to install python to use it, but for various reasons, it's not so simple to do so.  Therefore, I'm trying to think of the most hassle-free way to package this so that non-programmers (eg microbiologists) can use the program without worrying about their python distribution and virtual environments and other hassles.  Many people won't use the program if they have to install a python distribution, or virtual environment to get it going, and until the issues with the binaries are resolved, I need a workaround.

Is it possible to deliver a full virtual environment, and python distribution in a folder or something, so that anyone could just fire up the application?  EG they download the files, open a terminal, type "python thisprogram.py" and it just launches?  ImageJ kind of works like this.  If you had to share your python library with a complete novice, how would you do it?

I'm willing to accept any types of hacks and workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Check out dev ops tools like [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) or [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/). For example, you could write an ansible playbook that did everything you described with a single invocation. Or, you could just write a bash script that set up the venv and everything.

Or [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Comment: Could the bash script include python without necessarily installing python?  EG include a python distribution?

Comment: Well, Docker is fine.  Ansible requires python to be installed, and Puppet is massive overkill.  [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) is another option.

Comment: Sweet, vagrant looks pretty cool.  Do you guys know of any videos/tutorials specific to python?

Comment: So there's no way to just send a python distribution and libraries, and have the python dist point to the packages included?